# Socket Opening on Android Device

Tags: java, android, sockets

I know this seems a repeated question but it is not actually. I want to communicate with some sensors over sockets. The connection work fine on Emulator but when I upload it on Android Device it wont work. After Debugging I narrowed my app down to simple opening a socket using the following code.

```
try
{
 Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress).getHostAddress(), 10001);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
 Toast.makeText(context, "Error: "+e.getMessage(), duration).show();
}
```

I am simply opening a socket.This works fine on the emulator but when I run this app on the device it hangs for some time and shows me nothing not even the exception message... Any Idea what could be the problem. (Initially it was StrictMode problem but I sorted out). No error on the LogCat. I have installed android terminal emulator and tried ping, reply is fine. Thanks in advance

---

This is the code

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button btn;
    private CharSequence text = "";
    private Socket s;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
        .detectDiskReads()
        .detectDiskWrites()
        .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems
        .penaltyLog()
        .build());
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
        .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
        .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
        .penaltyLog()
        .penaltyDeath()
        .build());

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View view){
        //detect the view that was "clicked"
        switch(view.getId())
        {
          case R.id.button1:
              new LongOperation().execute("");
          break;

        }

    }

    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

          @Override
          protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

              try {
                    s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("o2215.airq.org").getHostAddress(), 10001);
                    text = "Connection Made";
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    text = "Error : ";
                    for(int i=0;i<e.getStackTrace().length;i++)
                    {
                        text = text +"\n"+ e.getStackTrace()[i];
                    }
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return "";
          }      

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
                txt.setText(text);
          }
    }
}
```

This works fine on the emulator, but not on the device.

Comment: I guess you thought of all the Permission stuff? SHould result in exceptions if not, but you didn't mention, so I'm asking just to be sure. Have you tried if you can open a connection to the target from somewhere else (other than emulator)?

Comment: what exactly is ipAddress? Addresses for the emulator and your device might differ (since the emulator has to go through your host's OS).

Comment: @Fildor yes I have given these permissions
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"> </uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"> </uses-permission>
I think this is why its working on emulator, otherwise it would result exceptions. And yes I can connect with the target from any browser and like I said I ping it with terminal emulator, works fine.

Comment: @SirRichie ipAddress is the ip of the sensor <id>.<domain>.org this can be accessed from any machine/any browser. Again like I said before I checked it from the device.

Comment: Does your device have the same Android version as the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this is because you try to make a connection in the main UI thread. Looks like you place the above code snippet inside your `Activity` class.

You should create a separate thread to make communications with network.

Use either simple  [`Thread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) or Android's wonderful [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply I tried with AsyncTask but no success but the device does not hang now (off course it runs in the background).
But at least I got some error
libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java.192)
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java.172)
java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)

Comment: It would be better as for you as for us if you would give an augmented  snippet of code where you establish the connection, because looking at the stack trace, it seems like you use third-party library and we need to know exactly.